# Why does my predict() function return the same class label every time

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, classification, prediction, decision-tree

I am working on a reimplementation of the ClassificationTree class in Matlab, I have implemented a findBestCutPoint() function and a buildTree() function. These work great albeit a little inefficient. The problem is when I get to the prediction phase, I am using a dataset that has 3 classes: setosa,virginica and versicolour. When I try and predict based off the tree I have built it outputs setosa everytime. This is confusing because the leaf nodes of my tree are pretty evenly varied between the 3 classes. I'm assuming it has something to do with the way I am traversing the tree but am a bit lost as to find the error as the logic checks out.

My Predict Method:

```
function predictions = predict(obj,test_exmaples)
    predictions = categorical;
    for i = 1:size(test_exmaples,1)
        currentNode = obj.Root;
        while true
            isLeaf = false;
            for j = 1:length(obj.Leaves)
                if currentNode.StartIndex == obj.Leaves{j}.StartIndex && currentNode.EndIndex == obj.Leaves{j}.EndIndex
                    isLeaf = true;
                    break;
                end
            end
            if isLeaf
                break;
            end
            if test_exmaples(i,currentNode.CutPredictorIndex) < currentNode.CutPoint
                currentNode = currentNode.Left;
            else
                currentNode = currentNode.Right;
            end
        end
        predictions(i) = currentNode.NodeClass;
    end
end
```

My Tree Building method:

```
function bestCut = findBestCutPoint(obj,node)%find the best cut point for the current node            
    bestCut.CutPoint = 0;
    bestCut.CutPredictorIndex = 0;
    bestCut.CutIndex = 0;
    bestCut.ShouldCut = true;
    bestGDI = Inf;
    parentLabels = obj.Y(node.StartIndex:node.EndIndex, 1);
    parentProbability = node.Size/length(obj.X);
    parentGDI = weightedGDI(parentLabels, obj.Y);
    parentSplitVal = parentProbability * parentGDI;
    minParentSize = obj.MinParentSize;
    for i = 1:size(obj.X,2)% Loop through all the features
        values = unique(obj.X(node.StartIndex:node.EndIndex, i));% Loop through all the unique values of the feature
        values = sort(values);
        for j = 1:length(values) % Calculate the weighted impurity of the two cuts
            leftLabels = obj.Y(node.StartIndex:node.EndIndex, 1);
            rightLabels = obj.Y(node.StartIndex:node.EndIndex, 1);

            leftProb = obj.X(node.StartIndex:node.EndIndex, i) < values(j);
            rightProb = obj.X(node.StartIndex:node.EndIndex, i) >= values(j);
            leftLabels = leftLabels(obj.X(node.StartIndex:node.EndIndex, i) < values(j));
            rightLabels = rightLabels(obj.X(node.StartIndex:node.EndIndex, i) >= values(j));
            leftSize = length(leftLabels);
            rightSize = length(rightLabels);
            leftProbability = length(leftProb)/length(obj.X);
            rightProbability = length(rightProb)/length(obj.X);

            leftGDI = weightedGDI(leftLabels, obj.Y);
            rightGDI = weightedGDI(rightLabels, obj.Y);
            
            cutGDI = ((leftProbability * leftGDI) + (rightProbability * rightGDI));% Calculate the weighted impurity of the split
            if cutGDI < bestGDI && leftSize >= minParentSize && rightSize >= minParentSize % Update the best split if the current split has a lower GDI
                bestGDI = cutGDI;
                value = (values(j) + values(j-1))/2;%added
                bestCut.CutPoint = value; %swapped values(j)
                bestCut.CutPredictorIndex = i;
                bestCut.CutIndex = find(obj.X(:, i) == values(j), 1, 'first');
            end
        end
    end
    if parentSplitVal < bestGDI
        bestCut.ShouldCut = false;
        return
    end
end

function treenode = buildTree(obj,node)
    if node.Size > 0
        CutPoint = findBestCutPoint(obj,node);
        if node.Size <= obj.MinParentSize || obj.CurrentNumSplits >= obj.MaxNumSplits  || CutPoint.ShouldCut == false || node.StartIndex == node.EndIndex %keeps getting stuck in here and then repeating the code
            node.Leaf = true;% Mark the node as a leaf node
            labels = obj.Y(node.StartIndex:node.EndIndex); %gather all the labels for the data in the nodes range
            node.NodeClass = mode(labels);%find the most frequent label and classify the node as such
            obj.Nodes{end+1} = node;%add the node to the Nodes cell array
            obj.Leaves{end+1} = node;
            treenode = node;%return the node so it can be added as a child
            return;
        else
            if node.StartIndex == CutPoint.CutIndex
                leftChild = Node(node.StartIndex, node.StartIndex);
                rightChild = Node(CutPoint.CutIndex +1, node.EndIndex);
            
            else
                leftChild = Node(node.StartIndex, CutPoint.CutIndex - 1);%create a node called left child with the same start index as the original node and end index as the last one before the cut index
                rightChild = Node(CutPoint.CutIndex, node.EndIndex);% create the right child node with the cut index as sindex and the same eindex as the original node
            end
            obj.CurrentNumSplits = obj.CurrentNumSplits + 1;%update the number of splits
            node.CutPoint = CutPoint.CutPoint;%save the cutpoint
            node.CutPredictorIndex = CutPoint.CutPredictorIndex;%save the cutpredictor index
            labels = obj.Y(node.StartIndex:node.EndIndex); %gather all the labels for the data in the nodes range
            node.NodeClass = mode(labels); %find the most frequent label and classify the node as such
            treenode = node;%return the node
            obj.Nodes{end+1} = treenode;
            
            node.Left = buildTree(obj,leftChild);%recusively build the tree from the left child and save it as the original nodes left child changed from CHILDREN{1} adding this to nodes instead of afterwards
            node.Right = buildTree(obj,rightChild);%recusively build the tree from the right child and save it as the original nodes right child
            %obj.Nodes{end+1} = treenode;%add the node to the nodes cell array
        end
    end
    treenode = node;
end
```

I have tried rewriting my predict method a couple of different ways but always get the same outcome.
This is similar to another post I made last year. However the problem then was with my buildTree method which I have now fixed.

Comment: Can you update your question with a link to your previous related post?

Comment: findBestCutPoint may be why you keep getting the same results. Take a look at how you calculate the cut point and make sure you use the midpoint.